# Trouble using Org Browser to :Retrieve Source to Org" and running into an error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, salesforce

**<Summary**
Within the same SFDX Project:• When attempting to use Org Browser component to "Retrieve Source from Org" for any specific component or overarching type (e.g. "Custom Objects/Account", "Custom Objects/Asset", "Apex Test Suites", consistently receiving ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'c:.forceignore' error message. No metadata is downloaded
• The same requests for metadata can be successfully executed from the "normal" VSCode Explorer view, right-clicking the metadata component and choosing the "SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org" option.

**Steps To Reproduce:**
See Summary above. Further, if manually copying/creating the complained about missing file (in this case "c:.forceignore"), it complains about another file -- in my particular case "c:.git". It is as if it's reading known files using a relative path, then trying to use an absolute path w/o the correct prefix value. I realize this is stretching. It's strange that these files being complained about have anything to do with retrieving and placing the metadata.

**Expected result**
Component metadata should be retrieved and be available in the SFDX project.

**Actual result**
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'c:.forceignore' error message.

**Additional information** None.

**Salesforce Extension Version in VS Code:**  
Salesforce CLI Integration: 58.3.1

**SFDX CLI Version: ** 
sfdx-cli/7.205.6 win32-x64 node-v18.15.0OS and version:  
Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 22H2, OS Build 19045.3086>

Within the same SFDX Project:• When attempting to use Org Browser component to "Retrieve Source from Org" for any specific component or overarching type (e.g. "Custom Objects/Account", "Custom Objects/Asset", "Apex Test Suites", consistently receiving ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'c:.forceignore' error message. No metadata is downloaded • The same requests for metadata can be successfully executed from the "normal" VSCode Explorer view, right-clicking the metadata component and choosing the "SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org" option